# Render a template into a string?

Tags: grails

Is it possible to "render" a template into a string? I would like to use a template and fill that with some values that I then must save to the local disc.

The render method always send the template to the client. I want something similar to run a template but save the output from the template to a local string variable that I can store in the local file system.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is simpler than you think:

```
def myTemplateString = g.render(template: "test", model: [foo: bar])
```

Comment: This does nothing, why is it the accepted answer? What is the "g" variable?

Comment: Also requires injecting the PageRenderer.

Comment: @Michael, that depends on where you use it. In a service you need groovyPageRenderer, but in the controller you can use the render method that is also available in the GSP. So `<g:render template="something"` can be called like `g.render(template: 'something')`.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Grails 2.x, you can use the PageRenderer class. Try something like this:

```
     grails.gsp.PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

     void methodName() { 
         def contents = groovyPageRenderer.render(template:"yourTemplate", model:yourModel)
         //you can use contents as a string now
     }
```

This will work outside the scope of a web request as well, such as in a scheduled job or web service.

Comment: This does not work in Tomcat 6 for at least Grails version 2.1.1 and below.

Comment: @JohnGiotta I believe you have to run in a container that supports Servlet 3.0 for this to work.

Comment: I'm running this from a service but I'm getting an extra slash in the urls for link and script tags generated by the Resources plugin, like this: "//static/...". Any ideas why?