# Render a controller into a String

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I can [render a template or a view into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983245/render-a-template-into-a-string), but how can I render a controller into a String ?

I would like to perform this kind of operation:

```
def myAction = {
  ...
  def html = renderToString(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction', params: [what:'ever'])
  render modify(html)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grails include tag](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) for this

```
def html= g.include(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction', params: [what:'ever'])
```

Comment: The called action MUST use a render directive itself, else it will throw an exception.